# JFormattedTextField and getValue vs. getText

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

After reading the docs it is not clear to me the difference between `getValue` and `getText` for a `JFormattedTextField`.

In my code, `getText` gives me what I think I need while `getValue` always returns null.

It seems to me, based on the docs, that they should both return the same thing at least after the field, when correctly formatted, loses focus.

The `getValue` method is supposed to "Returns the last valid value."

A simple explanation would be helpful.

Comment: Can you share the code. It might be possible that you are setting text (string) using the `setText()` method and retrieve text using `getValue()` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well `JFormattedTextField` is a text component that allows to keep a **value** and give it a custom String representation (format).

This value is an Object which is typically a Date or Number instance, the two classes with most different formats.

So having said this, [getValue()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html#getValue()) returns the value held by formatted text field component while [getText()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText()) returns the value's String representation.

For further details on this component please take a look to [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html):

> A formatted text field's *text* and its *value* are two different
>   properties, and the value often lags behind the text.
>
> The text property is defined by the JTextField class. This property
>   always reflects what the field displays. The value property, defined
>   by the JFormattedTextField class, might not reflect the latest text
>   displayed in the field. While the user is typing, the text property
>   changes, but the value property does not change until the changes are
>   committed.
>
> To be more precise, the value of a formatted text field can be set by
>   using either the setValue method or the commitEdit method. The
>   setValue method sets the value to the specified argument. The argument
>   can technically be any Object, but the formatter needs to be able to
>   convert it into a string. Otherwise, the text field does not display
>   any substantive information.

Comment: Thanks. I did not use commmitEdit. Can I assume if that is never used getValue will always return a null?

Comment: You are welcome. No, it's a little bit confusing but you should not call those methods explicitly except `setValue()` if you want to set an initial value. The thing is: 1) User types text with the format you tell the formatted text field to accept. When the edit is done then commitEdit method is called internally 2) If the text is valid and an Object can be parsed from the text inserted, then the value is set to the new one. In this case `getValue()` will return a non null value. 3) If the text is not valid then the value is not changed. If it never was set then `getValue()` will return null.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have

```
JFormattedTextField text = new JFormattedTextField(new DecimalFormat("####.##"));
```

This is a simple JFormatedTextField for numbers. You enter 12 (a valid entry), and both values will be the same. If you enter "Hello", this is invalid and will not be returned by getValue().

You have probably entered invalid data into the textfield.